# AngularJS Multiple Directive Resource Contention Error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am currently learning AngularJS on Udemy with the excellent `AngularJS JumpStart with Dan Wahlin` course. I am on Section 7 - Bonus: Getting Started Building Custom Directives.

I had defined a Hello World directive which was working fine; then I defined a new directive so that I could learn about shared vs isolate scope.

As soon as I include the second directive, I get the following error:

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [helloWorld, helloWorld] asking for template on: <hello-world>
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$compile/multidir?p0=helloWorld&p1=&p2=helloWorld&p3=&p4=template&p5=%3Chello-world%3E
```

[Here's a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SxAOIMWAcykTx5OGRFsa).

If I comment out the script that defines either one of these, the other one works.

Why is this happening? I've clearly named both directives differently, so why is Angular throwing an error that basically says I've declared the same directive twice?

Comment: Use chrome to debug more easily. on the console you can click on the error, it display a page on the angular website with more details on the error, ( full text and details ) not obscur minified like on the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is defining `directives` variable and adding it each time to the directives.
The more popular way of defining directives is:

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.directive('helloWorld', ....);
```

Or if you prefer it your way, either have all directives in the same file, or move `var directives = angular.module('app').directives` to app.js

Comment: Thanks! I figured I was being bone-headed and I realized that the error makes perfect sense if I take a step back and inspect `angular.module('app')._invokeQueue`. I've updated my Plunker to one that actually works here: http://plnkr.co/edit/SxAOIMWAcykTx5OGRFsa

Comment: As to why I prefer to define my directives, controllers, services, etc. in the way I have done, is to avoid magic strings (and thus typo issues) as much as possible. The popular way certainly works, but I've been burned by dumb typos in the past when defining things that way.

Answer (score 1):

1) you forget to add "plain:true" in the directives ( if you put directly your html code in template you have to put "plain:true" otherwise use templateUrl to your html file)

2) the problem come from the fact that you create two times the same angular module :

```
   var directives = angular.module('app').directives;
```

I update your plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/cYkgdYcHXGlbtMRJHRw2?p=preview

Comment: I figured it out; see [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34151231/angularjs-multiple-directive-resource-contention-error/34151585#comment56062347_34151585) on the accepted answer.